# Complete list of IEEE Software "Voice of Evidence" articles?

Tags: reference-request, software-engineering

This month the IEEE Software magazine has published the article [Voice of Evidence: A Look Back](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7974677/?source=tocalert&dld=Y2Vybi5jaA%3D%3D). This is a kind of impact analysis of the Voice of Evidence (VoE) series of articles.

As you know, these articles are meta-analysis about software engineering practices and they give invaluable information about which things likely work and which things do not likely work.

I wonder if anyone knows how to get the complete list of VoE references (with or without paywall).

Comment: Search on Google Scholar and IEEE Xplore?  Look through back issues of IEEE Software one by one?  I don't see how this is a question about computer science.

Comment: Obviously, I already tried to search before posting a question. These articles are a kind of updated versions of the book Software Engineering Facts and Fallacies. They try to answer some computer science questions by checking the existing evidence on the matter.